# What can i do when consecutive s's checker is broken

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need it to print `hiss` if there are any 2 consecutive s's and `no hiss` if not. But it's outputting `hiss` alone or `hiss` and `no hiss` at the same or it outputs `hiss` if there are 2 s's but nothing when there are no consecutive s's. I've tried to tweak the `range(len(word)-1,0,-1)` and the `if(not flag):`

Here's the Code:

```py
word=input()

if len(word)>30: raise Exception("Word too long")

flag=True

for i in range(len(word)-1,0,-1):
  if word[i] not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": raise Exception("Invalid Character")
  if word[i]=="s" and word[i-1]=="s":
    print("hiss")
    flag=False
    break

if(not flag): print("no hiss")
```

Please Help Me.

Comment: Why not simply use `if 'ss' in word` instead of a entire loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
if 'ss' in input():
    print('hiss')
else:
    print('not hiss')
```

If you need to use a loop for some reason, you can fix it it by changing the `if not flag` to `if flag`. Since if there is a `hiss`, flag will be false, it will be true if there is no double `ss` found anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know that it can be done by ss.